# How to combine specific elements from a Python list?

Tags: python

If I have a Python list, how can I combine some specific elements from the list?

My string looks like this:

```
my_string = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'And', 'Mouse', 'Whale', 'Cat', 'And', 'Mouse']
```

I want my new string to look like this:

```
new_string = ['Dog', 'Cat And Mouse', 'Whale', 'Cat And Mouse']
```

Here's my code so far (not correct):

```
new_string = iter(my_string)
my_string[:] = [i + next(new_string) if i == 'Cat' else i for i in new_string]
```

If I print my new string, I get:

```
['Dog', 'CatAnd', 'Mouse', 'Whale', 'CatAnd', 'Mouse']
```

Where am I going wrong? Thank you.

Comment: In your own words: when you find `Cat` in the input sequence, how many elements should be combined, *including* `Cat`? Where the code says `i + next(new_string)`, how many elements are combined? Do you see the problem? Please try to think through problems before asking, and make sure you [understand exactly what the code is doing, step by step](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). When the output is wrong, start by trying to look for a *pattern* in *how* it is wrong. Then try to look for an explanation for that pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sliding over the word triplets in the list:

```
my_string = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'And', 'Mouse', 'Whale', 'Cat', 'And', 'Mouse']

new_string = []
x = 0

while x < len(my_string) - 2:
    triplet = my_string[x:x+3]

    if len(triplet) == 3: # we have a full triplet
        if triplet[1] == "And":
            new_string.append(' '.join(triplet))
            x += 3 # skip next two elements
        else:
            new_string.append(triplet[0])
            x += 1
    else: # we are approaching the end of the list
        new_string.extend(triplet)
        break

print(new_string)
```

produces:

```
['Dog', 'Cat And Mouse', 'Whale', 'Cat And Mouse']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, just not going far enough — you are taking just one next element, when you want two. Also, you want a space between.

```
my_string[:] = [
    ' '.join(i, next(new_string), next(new_string)) if i == 'Cat' else i
    for i in new_string
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is one approach.  We can first form a single string of space separated words.  Then, use `re.findall` to first search for two words separated by `And`, and that failing, just find a single word.

```py
my_string = ['Dog', 'Cat', 'And', 'Mouse', 'Whale', 'Cat', 'And', 'Mouse']
output = re.findall(r'\w+ And \w+|\w+', ' '.join(my_string))
print(output)  # ['Dog', 'Cat And Mouse', 'Whale', 'Cat And Mouse']
```